# ElasticSearch asynchronous multimaster synchronization

Tags: synchronization, elasticsearch

I am trying to implement asynchronous multimaster synchronization for many nodes. Nodes are using ElasticSearch NOSQL database and they can go offline and back online anytime. How can it be done? Are there any tools that can handle it? Or can I somehow sync files that are used by ES? Thank you.

Comment: So you want to have a fault tolerant, distributed Elasticsearch cluster? This is built-in behavior.

Comment: Each node runs it's own ES server with own local database. Nodes can insert/modify/delete data while they cannot be reached from other nodes (they are disconnected from network, but ElasticSearch is running locally). When they go back online I want to sync changes with other nodes. 
So data are asynchronously bidirectional synchronized. Also ES can be stopped and started before synchronization begins. Is this build-in function? How are changes captured? Where are they stored? How are data conflicts solved?